# Java, UnmarshallingException caused by XML attribute with special chars: ;ìè+òàù-<^èç°§_>!£$%&/()=?~`'#;

Tags: java, xml, schema, special-characters, unmarshalling

my xml file has a tag with an attribute "containsValue" which contains the "special" characters you can see in the subject:

```
<original_msg_body id="msgBodySpecialCharsRule" containsValue=";ìè+òàù-<^èç°§_>!£$%&/()=?~`'#;" />
```

in my xml schema the attribute has xs:string:

```
<xs:attribute name="containsValue" type="xs:string"  />
```

I use this value inside a Java software which check if this value is contained inside another String.

but I always obtain this Exception:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The value of attribute "containsValue" associated with an element type "original_msg_body" must not contain the '<' character.]
```

How can I solve it? I've tried changing the attribute type to xs:NMTOKEN, ut I get the same exception. Is there any other type?

I think I could change the characters encoding, for example using the HTML representation, like <, but than could be tricky for the string comparison...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape special XML entities like `<`, `>`, `"` with `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&quote;`

Comment: I was thinking something like that, in my question I said "...the HTML representation, like <,..." where you see the "<" because I forgot to click on the "code" button in the editor.

Answer (score 3):

Use entity references: replace `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt` etc. in your XML document.  Your XML parser will then handle conversion between actual character and its entity reference. That is, in your code you get the actual `<` or `>` character.

Comment: +1 - Exactly, a bare '<' or '>' or '"' character in an XML attribute value makes the XML malformed ... or in rare cases, well-formed but different to what you meant.